# English translation of Kuzari Sheini

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, translation

Does anyone know of an online English translation of the [Kuzari Sheini](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22434&pgnum=1) by R' David Nieto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's one](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/IOlhAAAAcAAJ) by [Louis Loewe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Loewe), from 1842.